Relationship between the variance of poisson distribution and the exponential distribution
Poisson and Exponential distributions are related. But the variance of poisson is $\lambda$, which is equal to the mean and represent the average number of events in a unit time. However, variance of exponential is $1/\lambda^2$, which is not equal to the mean $1/\lambda$ of the distribution. On the other hand, the mean of the two distributions ($\lambda$ and $1/\lambda$) multiply to one, which feels nice considering that both are modelling some events in a period of time where there is a known average probability of happening.
How can we understand this difference in variance? Why is it that when some thing on average happens N times in a period of time, after modelled by poisson, has only a deviation of $\sqrt\lambda$ (imagine some thing that happens 4 times in one hour, then on average, it will happen 2 or 6 times) while the average waiting time for the same event will be on average 15 minutes （and on average deviate from 0 to 30 minutes）. Is there any way we can have an intuitive connection between the variances here?

Essentially the behaviour of the exponential distribution is equivalent to rescaling (the mean and the standard deviation change proportionately to each other), while the behaviour of the Poisson distribution is similar to summing i.i.d. random variables (the mean and the variance change proportionately to each other).
We are discussing the parameter $\lambda$ in both distributions.

For the exponential distribution, $\lambda$ is proportional to the reciprocal of scale.  So both the expectation and the standard deviation must be proportional to $\frac1\lambda$ and the variance proportional to $\frac1{\lambda^2}$.  In fact, for the exponential distribution, the constant of proportionality is $1$ in all three cases.

For the Poisson distribution, if you sum $n$ independent identically distributed Poisson distributions, you get a another Poisson distribution; since these are i.i.d., the sum must have an expectation $n$ times the original expectation and a variance $n$ times the original variance and so a standard deviation $\sqrt{n}$ times the original standard deviation.  You can easily extend this argument to rational multiples and with more sophistication to real multiples, so the expectation and variance must each be proportional to $\lambda$ and the standard deviation proportional to $\sqrt{\lambda}$.  In fact, for the Poisson distribution, the constant of proportionality is $1$ in all three cases.


With a larger $\lambda$, so a higher rate, you typically see smaller exponentially distributed gaps between events and a higher Poisson distributed number of events.  The effect on an exponential distribution is simple rescaling while keeping the same exponential shape, but for $X$ with a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$, you find $\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \to \mathcal N(0,1)$ in distribution as $\lambda$ increases, similar to the central limit theorem.

Thank you. I think you have done a good job conveying the difference between the two distributions. However, my question is, if poisson distribution and exponential distribution imply each other, how can we understand this difference in variance. In other words, how can we use layman terms to explain one with bigger spread and another with smaller spread while they model things that are closely related to each other?

@Derren:  That is easier: the exponential distribution is for the gaps between events in a Poisson process, while the Poisson distribution is for the number of events in a time interval.  So if the rate of events increases, then the gaps tend to get smaller on average (with a similar scaling effect on the standard deviation of the length of the gaps) and the number of events tends to get larger (with the variance of this number also increasing).

Yes I guess my question is exactly why one has this scaling effect and the other one does not have it. Another way of looking at it, if we double the rate, then mean of occurrence double and mean of wait time is halved. This feels right since within a period of time occurrence double means wait time halved on average. But, variance of occurrence will double but variance of wait time is quartered. It's like we are more sure of wait time than average occurrence of the event. In one bracket you mentioned sd, the other, variance. If these distributions are born together, why not spread similarly?

@DerenLiu Because with the exponential distribution, increasing the rate is a pure scaling effect with no effect on shape, while with the Poisson distribution it is like summing iid random variables (so more concentrated around the expectation than pure scaling would be).
